# Attaching temperature sensors to solar cells

Tags: sensor, power-electronics, solar-cell, temperature, heat

For my project, I have to find the temperature coefficients of the solar module that I am using. Meaning that I need to calculate the change in voltage, current and power with respect to temperature of a solar module.

In order to do so, I need to attach a thermistor to the back side of a solar module and continuously record the temperature (using arduino). I am going to be using an epoxy  thermistor and thermal curing glue to attach it to the module.

Is there another way to do it? Any recommendations as to which thermistor to use (bare or epoxy based) and which glue or grease or paste or tape or another way in general?

Comment: How rapidly do you expect the temperature to change? Perhaps it would be sufficient to come to it with a laser temp meter every X minutes and measure it and record in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Quite rapidly and I would want to record it every 15 seconds or so for the first 10 minutes. It is expected that after 30 minutes, a leveled (saturated) temperature will be reached. The solar module will be placed under a solar simulated, so I cannot point it with a laser ever 'x' minutes.

Comment: Instead of a thermistor I'd use something more advanced and easier to use, the DS18B20, see http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/ds18b20-arduino  These are easy to use with Arduino and need no extra components. The Epoxy based glue sounds fine, I would not use tape as the glue on tape can get loose at higher temperatures and tape ages. Epoxy glue will be much more stable.

Comment: Would a normal K-type thermistor do the job for you?

Comment: K type suggests thermocouple rather than thermistor.

Comment: I would just use a K-type thermocouple. Not the most accurate, but the temperature change should be pretty accurate. Fast curing epoxy or CA glue should work for attachment. Important: cover it with a small piece of foam tape after you glue it so that it is insulated from air temperature. You want to measure the panel temperature, not the air temperature.  Secure the wire leads with tape or zip ties so that you don't accidentally rip it off while you are setting up the test.

Comment: There are little modules you can get for arduino (or any micro controller with an ADC) which convert k-type thermocouple to a suitable voltage range for sampling. Google "thermocouple amplifier" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there another way to do it?

Yeah, you could just tape it to the solar module. If you need thermal conductivity you could apply thermal paste around the thermistor. If you have air around the thermistor, the more thermal resistivity you will have and the longer the thermistor will take to equalize to the solar module. Kapton tape is great becasue it is high temperature.

The idea is you'd want the thermal resistivity between the module to be low enough to equalize to the modules temperature. Since the module itself is proabably going to have a much larger time constant than the thermistor, the thermistor will proabably equalize even if you had a small point of contact. To be sure you could put a small dab of thermal grease on it and tape it on. Taping the thermistor wire to the module will also help equalize the temeprature.

You could use a thermal epoxy also, but you would be dealing with epoxy which isn't that fun.

As far as thermistor type, get one that has the temperature range and accuracy you need.